# How to upload file using Alamofire with base64EncodedString?

Tags: ios, file-upload, swift3, alamofire

How to upload base64EncodedString on the server using `Alamofire.upload`?

My upload file URL accepts the file in base64.
And when the upload completes sending the response in JSON format.
How to upload and read the response?

```
func uploadWithAlamofire() {

    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cartest")

    let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData

 // let imagencoded:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

    let params = ["token": "454545sddsddf",
                  "filepath": "/",
                  "filearea": "draft"]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "filecontent", fileName: "filetest.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }

        for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: "http://myuploadurl.php", method: .post,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.response { [weak self] response in
                        guard let strongSelf = self else {
                            return
                        }
                        debugPrint("DATA RESPOND======== \(response)")
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please use documentation. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/

Comment: I guess this is for objective C?

Comment: Show your current code.

Comment: I have added my code.